# Gcal api throwing error

Tags: zend-framework, google-calendar-api, gcal

I am using zendgdata library for google calendar.

I am getting this error while using this function createQuickAddEvent(it add events to the the google calendar).

Code of this function is:

```
/**
 * Creates an event on the authenticated user's default calendar using 
 * the specified QuickAdd string.
 *
 * @param Zend_Http_Client $client The authenticated client object
 * @param string $quickAddText The QuickAdd text for the event
 * @return string The ID URL for the event
 */
function createQuickAddEvent ($client, $quickAddText) {
    $gdataCal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);
    $event = $gdataCal->newEventEntry();
    $event->content = $gdataCal->newContent($quickAddText);
    $event->quickAdd = $gdataCal->newQuickAdd(true);

    $newEvent = $gdataCal->insertEvent($event);
    return $newEvent->id->text;
    }
```

**Error: Expected response code 200, got 403**

May be this is due to the fact i have not loaded google calendar(setting timezone first time when you click google calendar). After loading google calendar this error never comes.But i want a solution to this.This thing should never happen with a new user.

Please help me

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, I think I'd completely misunderstood you.

Do you mean you want to add an event to a calendar but the calendar *doesn't even exist yet*? No, you can't do that. The user will have to sign up to Google Calendar before you can try to use it.

Apart from anything else, creating a calendar involves the user agreeing to terms of service and a privacy policy. While we *may* have some way of automating all that - probably for validated partners, where we'd check that the application asked for the same consent - I highly doubt that it's available through Gdata.

Comment: Thanks for replying but i am passing clientobject then why this is happening & can you please elaborate how can i authenticate explicitly?

Comment: Yes, you're passing in a client object - but has it been authenticated? See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.authsub.html for explicit authsub authentication.

Comment: Thanks once again i just want to confirm whether a user should configure google calendar first in order to create events through my application without any errors.

Comment: Thanks for your reply got my answer